# How can i get client machine timezone by using IP Address in C# without using Javascript and Cookies?

Tags: timezone, utc, cultureinfo, timezone-offset

I need to convert input date time to UTC format and save client machine time zone standard name, so i need standard timezone id for client machine with DST. My input is only IP Address from request header.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get a time zone from just an IP address.

You need location information - latitude and longitude.  If you are communicating with a mobile device, you may be able to get these through GPS or cell-tower triangulation.

Once you have coordinates, you can use one of the techniques outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824).

You could consider using a service that performs IP geolocation to get coordinates from the IP address.  However, this is unreliable because you might not have the true IP address of the end-user.  You might be looking at the IP address of a proxy server or router in some other time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
TimeZoneInfo.Local.DaylightName;
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. The code isn't being executed on the local machine; the timezone needs to be determined from the IP address.